# FaceDetectionListener does not work on Xperia, maybe caused by "Not granting permission com.sonymobile.permission.SYSTEM_UI_VISIBILITY_EXTENSIONS"

Tags: android, face-detection, sony, android-permissions, sony-xperia

Im working on Android application development.

PROBLEM:

All I want is just enable face detection on my application, but it does not work.
I've already tried multiple sample codes given on books, webs, but no one succeeded.
Probably these 2 alerts show the cause:

> W/WindowManager﹕ Access to extended visibility flags denied: Requires com.sonymobile.permission.SYSTEM_UI_VISIBILITY_EXTENSIONS permission.

and

> W/ServiceManager﹕ Permission failure: com.sonyericsson.permission.CAMERA_EXTENDED

Even if I added

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.sonymobile.permission.SYSTEM_UI_VISIBILITY_EXTENSIONS"  android:protectionLevel="normal" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.sonyericsson.permission.CAMERA_EXTENDED"/>
```

it says

> W/PackageManager﹕ Not granting permission com.sonymobile.permission.SYSTEM_UI_VISIBILITY_EXTENSIONS to package com.example.facedetect (protectionLevel=18 flags=0x8be46)
>
> W/PackageManager﹕ Not granting permission com.sonyericsson.permission.CAMERA_EXTENDED to package com.example.facedetectbybook (protectionLevel=2 flags=0x8be46)

Can anyone help me?
I use Android Studio, Xperia M C1905 with android-ver. 4.3.
I already did followings:

.change protection level to signature

.make sure params.getMaxNumDetectedFaces() is more than 1 (its 5)

.min sdk version: 14

Comment: You might try the new Android face detector API.  This is a software solution, so it does not require hardware feature permissions like you are trying above (although it does require a general camera permission).  See:  https://developers.google.com/vision/

Comment: Thank you for informing, it looks worth trying.  I will:)